# Google Cloud Storage and redirecting url

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, hosting, web-hosting

is it possible to set url redirecting from url without www to url with www ex.

exampleDomain.com returns an error but www.exampleDomain.com works properly. Workaround which I found was htaccess file but it doesn't work on Google Cloud Platform Storage and bucket.

Comment: Use a Google Cloud Load Balancer with the bucket as the backend. You can then setup rules. https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/adding-backend-buckets-to-load-balancers

Comment: Hi @DanielStankiewicz, have you tried creating a custom 301 HTML page that redirects all the `www.example.com` traffic to `example.com`? Check out the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#optional_assigning_index_and_error_pages)